# Are reversible and irreversible processes frame dependent?

Tags: thermodynamics, special-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames, reversibility

since it is all about time. If I have a look at an irreversible process from a frame where time runs really slow. is there a possibility of considering that process reversible from that frame?

Comment: So now time slows down for you, but how would that affect the irreversibly issue in your question? No matter how slowly time passes for you, imo 2nd law of thermodynamics still holds in all timelike frames, so an irreversible process is invariant in all timelike intervals.

Comment: Whether the second law will hold or not is not my question . My question is if i consider it to be a really fast event in one frame and hence say it is irreversible, that statement shouldn't hold if i am looking at that event from a frame in which time runs really slow and the event runs really slow as well .

Comment: Hi  I'm not sure as to how you make a connection between  going very fast and a process being irreversible? Could you please explain about that aspect? Regards

Comment: An irreversible process is one for which $\Delta S = 0$. It doesn't matter what Lorentz frame you are in, if this holds in one such frame it will hold in all.